# yeoman and angular on digitalocean doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, digital-ocean

I try run angularjs with yeoman on digitalocean but I receive error

[image: yeoman error]

Comment: Are you logged into the root user? Have you performed `npm install`? Does your current user have read/execute permissions in the `/root/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while trying to use the Keystone generator.

I solved the issue by creating a new user (I had been logged in as the root user via a cloud9 workspace) with root privileges and then running yo as that new user.